# i want to save my file if condition met. I have written below code but its not working

Tags: excel, vba

Here i want to compare three values and if three values are equal then only it should save as the file.

```
Sub test()


    m = 1
    n = 1
    b = 5


    If m = n = b Then Sheet1.Activate

    Sheet1.Copy

    MsgBox "This new workbook will be saved as MyWb.xls(x)"

    'Save new workbook as MyWb.xls(x) into the folder where ThisWorkbook is stored
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MNP", xlWorkbookNormal
    MsgBox "It is saved as " & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & vbLf & "Press OK to close it"

    ' Close the saved copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False




    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any error output? Did you debugged it to see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One way to go:

To compare data in the If statement you need to add logical operators. It's the same if you want to say `m = n` or `b = a`. [So add AND in this case](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/and_vba.php).

When you apply `If` you also need to end with `End If`

```
Sub tsat()

Dim m As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim b As Long


m = 1
n = 1
b = 1


If (m = n And m = b) Then

Sheet1.Activate

Sheet1.Copy

MsgBox "This new workbook will be saved as MyWb.xls(x)"

'Save new workbook as MyWb.xls(x) into the folder where ThisWorkbook is stored
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MNP", xlWorkbookNormal
MsgBox "It is saved as " & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & vbLf & "Press OK to close it"

' Close the saved copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Else

MsgBox "Values are not equal. " & " m=" & m & ", n=" & n & ", b=" & b

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If m = n And n = b And b = m Then` is a tad redundant. If the first two are true then the last *must* be true.

Comment: Could also´be written as: `If (m = n And m = b) Then`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Yes, when I look more into it I saw that :P

Comment: What if i want to give some message when values are not same then how can do that?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Glad it worked :)!! Please mark the answer as accepted so other people can see that the question is solved. Grey check mark under the voting buttons in the answer. Take care :)!! [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do - but if you want to save sheet1 as a copy under a different name then

```
Sub Demo

Dim m,n,b
If application.worksheetfunction.And(m=n,m=b) then
    dim wbTarget as workbook
    set wbtarget = workbooks.add()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).copy before:=wbtarget.sheets(1)
    wbTarget.saveas ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MNP.xlsx"
    wbtarget.close
    msgbox "Sheet 1 has been saved as MNP.xlsx"
end if
end Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet1.Copy` will automatically create a new workbook, with just the copied sheet.

Comment: You're mixing up your formulae with your VBA, the IF statement should probably look more like `IF (m = n AND m = b) Then`.

Comment: Whoops, yes should be If Application.WorksheetFunction.And(m = n, m = b) Then

Comment: Did you try running this code before submitting it?